# Placing map grid in appropriate order in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, grids-graticules, draw-order

I am creating a map, in which I have the map grid (thin grey lines crossing the entire map) and feature labels (converted to annotation stored in map). In some places, the map grid intersects the labels and reduces their readability. Instead of moving the labels, I want to change the order of the map grid so that it is below all the labels. At the same time, however, it should overlie all the shapefiles. I tried to convert the grid to graphics, but it didn't help because I was only able to place it either completely above or below the any other map content.

Is there a way how to deal with this issue in ArcMap 10.3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The map grid will always be on top of the map data in the data frame. That includes features, labels and annotation. There are a couple of workarounds that I have used.

- You can place the annotation in Layout View instead of Data View that way those labels can be placed on top of everything else.
- You tried converting the grid to graphics which is another option. After you do that it is in a new group element. Select that group element, right click and Ungroup. Some of the elements are in other groups which may need to be ungrouped. Now the individual pieces can be ordered. Select, right click, Order, Bring to Front, Send to Back etc.
- Another option is to not draw the grid lines as a Map Grid or graphic lines, but create a shapefile or feature class of the grid (eg UTM lines) then you can order it with the rest of your data.

Comment: Thank you very much for all your suggestions. I followed the third option and it worked well.using Grid Index Features tool and it worked well. Further, creating a shapefile

Comment: Thank you very much for all your suggestions. I followed the third option and it worked well.using Grid Index Features tool and it worked well. Further, creating a shapefile

Comment: Thank you very much for all your suggestions. I followed the third option and it worked well. I created a shapefile using Grid Index Features tool, which gives me better control over the feature order.